# The exception isn't captured by catch block

Tags: c++, exception, gdb

Somewhere (yeah, old compiler gcc 4.0.1 makes me sad):

```
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<xmlpp::DomParser> PtrDomParser;
```

This is the piece of my code:

```
try{
    //here I'm using xml++ library to handle xml

    PtrDomParser parser = cdata_file_to_parser(responseFilePath);
    xmlpp::Document *response = parser->get_document();
    xmlpp::NodeSet nodeSet;
    xmlpp::Node *node;
    xmlpp::Element *root;
    typedef xmlpp::NodeSet::iterator It;

    root = response->get_root_node();

    //... some code ...
    throw Exception(); 
}
catch (const Exception &exc){
    std::cout << "Exception is captured!" << std::endl;
}
catch (...){
    std::cout << "Something else is captured!" << std::endl;
}
```

There are the facts:

**1.** It happens NOT everytime the flow reaches "throw Exception();", most of time the exception is captured.

**2.** Sometimes when the flow reaches (it does, 100%) "throw Exception();" - the exception is not captured, the program freezes, and when I try to attach to the program with gdb and type "where" - I see this:

1. 0xb7fd8430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
2. 0xb7d9bece in _lll_mutex_lock-wait() from /lib/i686/libpthread.so.0
3. 0xb7d98500 in _L_mutex_lock_71 () from /lib/i686/libpthread.so.0
4. 0xbfbefab8 in ?? ()
5. 0x00000000 in ?? ()
6. 0x00000000 in ?? ()

**3.** gcc 4.0.1, gdb 6.3 and I can't update them yet.

**5.** xml++ library (https://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/)

**6.** Well, the program uses many threads, I even don't know how they do work and what they do completely (the large project at my job), but I know, that I don't use any shared variables or smth else that can cause this behavior

**5.** Well, I think there is something wrong with xmlpp destructors, but I don't know what it is and I don't know how to trace it or how to figure it out

**update:**

I didn't find out where the issue is, but sometimes I meet with one more issue similar to first one (sigh..):

The issue occurs right after function(the another one) ends, when the shared_ptr destructor is called.

Again, I attached to the process, typed "where" and gdb said that:

========================

0) 0xb7fd8430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()

1) 0xb7d9bece in _lll_mutex_lock-wait() from /lib/i686/libpthread.so.0

2) 0xb7d98500 in _L_mutex_lock_71 () from /lib/i686/libpthread.so.0

..dunno what is here, I see only " .. in ?? ()"

10) .. in __gthread_mutex_lock

11) .. in __gthread_mutex_lock

12) .. in std::tr1::_Sp_counted_base::release

13) .. in ~shared_count

14) .. in ~shared_ptr

=======================

Seems it like shared_ptr is broken? 
Moreover, I was surprised to discover, that when I use std::tr1::shared_ptr, the boost_shared_ptr.h is used(the gdb said that, wtf?)

Comment: Smells like a deadlock?

Comment: It does, but probably there is the issue in library and I don't know how to trace it

Comment: use `thread apply all backtrace` in gdb and check which other threads wait for locks. Maybe you'll find which lock is the culprit. Also, you might try `helgrind` if that's available.

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of code necessary to reproduce the error. Then reduce it still further. You might find *your* error that way. If you don't, send the minimal example to the library maintainers for inspection, because if it's a bug in the xml++ library, they'll be happy about a precise bug report.

Comment: Thank you guys, I tried to use "thread apply all backtrace" and now I see much information, that might help, I need a time to explore it now. If it's a xml++ lib bug - then I will send it to the maintainers